# Exception Notification in Java

Tags: java, exception, notifications

Are there any good exception notification systems for web apps using Tomcat? Looking for libraries equivalent of exception_notification etc. which are available as plugins for Rails.

Comment: is "exception notification" == "logging" ?

Comment: @Bozho: "exception notification" == send email on error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html from log4j and also an extension I'm describing at http://blog.cherouvim.com/a-better-smtpappender/