# Java notification when runtime exception occurs

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception

I'm developing a java app which will be used on a server. Thus, it would be nice to notify (send an email) someone when a (uncaught) runtime exception occurs within the whole program. Is there a way to register a handler to react to a runtime exception occuring somewhere in the program?

thx & regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242756/exception-notification-in-java ?

Comment: You can add an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` which sends an email.